# Import Kanna in playground

Tags: ios, swift, import, xcode7, swift-playground

Is there a way to add Kanna (https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna) to Playground in XCode?
I have tried to install it manually and via CocoaPods, but with no luck. I have also tried to pack it inside a Framework, but still no luck.
Would appreciate any input.

These are the error messages I am most often encountering:

[image]

Comment: did you add this `use_frameworks!` also to your podfile

Comment: Yes, that is included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an interesting library in Github that allows run pods in Playground.It's still so young but it's very good. It's create a new project with the pod or pods installed and ready to test in the Playground.

- [ThisCouldBeUsButYouPlaying](https://github.com/neonichu/ThisCouldBeUsButYouPlaying)

I tested with your library and works fine:

```
//: Please build the scheme 'KannaPlayground' first
import XCPlayground
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

import Kanna

let html = "<html><a>Hello World</a></html>"

if let doc = Kanna.HTML(html: html, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
  print(doc.title)

  // Search for nodes by CSS
  for link in doc.css("a, link") {
      print(link.text)
      print(link["href"])
  }

  // Search for nodes by XPath
  for link in doc.xpath("//a | //link") {
     print(link.text)
     print(link["href"])
  }
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks for showing me a very interesting library! It looked promising, but I ended up with the same error messages as before. It print outs the following: could not build Objective-C module 'libxml2' in playground!

Comment: @fisher You may have a problem with your Xcode install. I just did `pod playgrounds Kanna` then CMD+R in the workspace that was automatically opened, to build Kanna, and now Kanna works in the Playground.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll try some more! I did a test with 'pod playgrounds Alamofire' and that fired up just fine in Playground.

Comment: I was able to get it working after reading this issue: https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna/issues/49. It's weird that it only affects some of us. So i did 'pod playgrounds Kanna', opened up the Podfile, editet it to force Kanna to use version 1.0.2 (pod 'Kanna', '1.0.2'), ran 'pod update', and voilà!. Either way, a great solution to work with pods in Playground. Marked as accepted!

Comment: @fisher Yes indeed a really great library to test pod in Playgrounds, I hope it continue improving its features.

Answer (score 1):

@slabko (and others). In order to get this working:

I found this from cocoapods github issues.

Manually add the pod frameworks via Link Binary With Libraries on the non-framework target.
Couple other caveats to keep in mind:

Classes or protocols defined in the pod that need to be accessible in the playground, must be marked public.
When dealing with a pod you've created, adding a playground directly to your framework's project will probably not allow importing the pod. One workaround is to create a "sample" project, include the pod and add your playground to that (then manually add frameworks per above ^).

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2240 for reference if you want to know more

thanks to @davidbjames

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have tried that, and still no success. I think it is because Kanna requires Obj-C modules that Playground is not able to locate. I'll do some more digging. Thanks again!