# Error with Alamofire.request(.GET, "www.example.com")

Tags: swift, alamofire

I work with ( 10.11.4 OS X and Xcode 7.2.1). I downloaded the framework with GitHub and install it, done. After I install it with the step-by-step instruction from Apple (Importing Custom Frameworks Into a Playground) and I have no error, when I type « import Alamofire ».But when I type au get request I don’t have some response. I Start « Product - Clean » and « Product - Build » no change. What is wrong?

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80hKu.jpg)

Comment: If what you want is test libraries in Playgrounds I strongly recommend a new library to import pods directly in Playgrounds, see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35735193/import-kanna-in-playground/35736467#35736467

Answer (score 1):

You might need to turn on infinite execution because these request are asynchronous.

```
import XCPlayground
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```